# Jest issues while running tests without flag --runInBand - my test fails

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs

I'm having some problems with my node tests with jest.
When I write the command to run the tests without the *--runInBand* flag, some of my tests fail. And when I try to run with the *--runInBand* flag they all pass...

It's always a good option to use the *--runInBand* flag? Or I did something wrong?
(I'm working with some async tests...)

Comment: This means that tests compete for same resources like db or depend on each other.  It's rarely a good option to use runInBand, otherwise it would be enabled by default. This disables concurrency which is one of major Jest benefits. Since you didn't provide any details, it's impossible to say what's wrong on your side.

Comment: well, unfortunatelly I can't show my code because it's from a private company. But I'm using sequelize to help fetching the data from db (i'm using mysql). And before each test i'm truncating the data using the destroy method from each model. One of the errors that's showing is : 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails'. That's happening when I'm storing into the database a row that contains a foreign key (which exists - i stored into the database the foreign key first). And when I use the flag --runInBand this error doesn't appear..

Comment: You don't need to show your proprietary code, but https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is necessary for code-related questions. If tests write to same tables at the same time, they will obviously fail at some point. You likely need to set up a separate unique tables or dbs for each test, this way they can be executed in parallel.

Comment: Oh... I see, thanks for the answer. I think I'm going to use the flag because I got a lot of tests and to separate unique dbs for each test may not be the best solution for now... Those tests are correlated because they're accessing the same information (e.g. the users table, one of the tests is to create new users and the other is to update the user information, so it's causing deadlock issues)